# iOS app name taken

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I've finished app and ready to submit it to ap store.
Before choosing name I've searched in US, Singapore and Irish app stores and haven't find any app with same or similar name. So I've ordered logo, splashscreen, created website, made screencast, registered FB and twitter accounts. Of course everywhere I've used my app name. 
So imagine how I was surprised whe iTunes Connect told me that name is taken! 
I've searched internet and found that few years ago someone released game with same name! Game already left app store, but name is still unavailable.
I've tried to find contacts of the developer and found her Facebook and Twitter. But looks like accounts already not in use. I haven't found her mail though...

Do you have any suggestions what I can do with that?
I think may be *AppName for iPad* instead of *AppName* will save situation. But then I'll need to change splashscreen, website, FB and twitter etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a search in the internet isn't enough as you can request a name 90 days before you submit an app. But I don't have any clever advice.

Comment: Depending on the name you may be able to only use "AppName for iPad" on the app store, but keep using "AppName" by itself everywhere else. For example you would probably still use just "AppName" as the home screen app name.

Comment: @JoeRasq Won't apple reject the app if on the splash screen it will be just AppName without iPad part?

Comment: @dasdom - that is my first AppStore release. I'll be more smart next time. I know that it is my mistake.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AppName for iPad is an option, but it might be better to add a little suffix describing what your app does. A lot of big name apps ("Elements - Dropbox And Markdown Powered Text Editor", "Convert ~ the unit calculator", "Faces - photo fun!") do exactly that.

This way your product name is the same, you can keep your existing marketing assets and you also get to sell the benefits of your app to potential customers.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I just did it and then checked stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thank you for this. Good point that it gets more info about the app to the user.

Comment: are you then allowed to present the condensed name (in this case AppName) as the name of the app on the home screen?